# FLV video conversion using ffmpeg fails with "Changing frame properties on the fly is not supported"

Tags: ffmpeg, video-conversion

I am facing a problem while converting .flv videos using ffmpeg. The output file format also has an extension of .flv. This is my command:

```
ffmpeg -i 8617854d-77e1-4538-b7ea-2853bcb06ee2.flv -s 400x240 -vcodec flv -b 500k -r 18000000/642857 -ar 11025 -y out.flv
```

The error:

```
[buffer @ 0x23bf080] Changing frame properties on the fly is not supported
```

and this is the output message on the terminal:

```
Seems stream 0 codec frame rate differs from container frame rate: 28.00 (18000000/642857) -> 14.00 (18000000/1285714)  
Input #0, flv, from '8617854d-77e1-4538-b7ea-2853bcb06ee2.flv':
  Metadata:
    creationdate    : Wed Jan 29 09:14:32    
    Duration: 00:03:37.21,   
    start: 0.007000,   
    bitrate: N/A Stream #0.0: Video: h264 (Baseline), yuv420p, 264x198 [PAR 1:1 DAR 4:3], 14 tbr, 1k tbn, 28 tbc
    Stream #0.1: Audio: libspeex, 16000 Hz, 1 channels, s16  
[buffer @ 0x23bf080] w:264 h:198 pixfmt:yuv420p  
[scale @ 0x23c1040] w:264 h:198 fmt:yuv420p -> w:400 h:240 fmt:yuv420p flags:0x4  
[libspeex @ 0x23bc880] Missing Speex header, assuming defaults.
Output #0, flv, to 'out.flv':  
  Metadata:  
    creationdate    : Wed Jan 29 09:14:32  
    encoder         : Lavf53.21.1
    Stream #0.0: Video: flv, yuv420p, 400x240 [PAR 4:5 DAR 4:3], q=2-31, 500 kb/s, 1k tbn, 28 tbc  
    Stream #0.1: Audio: libmp3lame, 11025 Hz, 1 channels, s16, 500 kb/s  
Stream mapping:    
  Stream #0.0 -> #0.0  
  Stream #0.1 -> #0.1  
Press ctrl-c to stop encoding    
[buffer @ 0x23bf080] Changing frame properties on the fly is not supported.
    Last message repeated 1562 times
                                     420kB time=9.71 bitrate= 353.8kbits/s    
frame=   71 fps= 24 q=2.5 Lsize=    2104kB time=9.71 bitrate=1774.3kbits/s    
video:339kB audio:1698kB global headers:0kB muxing overhead 3.262082%
```

I am currently using a Debian system (Wheezy) with ffmpeg version 0.8.9-6:0.8.9-1.

**Updated** :
Updated current installation to 'git-2014-01-31-dd4237f' .
My main intention was to convert the video to fill up some gaps in the meta info like Video bitrate , Audio bitrate etc ., which seem to be missing from the file .The input file is a webcam recorded file (recording done through 'OpenTok') , which is causing the video to not play on a flash player like flowplayer .  This is the complete output from the latest ffmpeg build :

```
    ffmpeg -i a91274db-595c-43cc-86f5-30824d4c9527 -vcodec libx264 -acodec copy -s 400x240 -ar 22050  -y out.flv
ffmpeg version git-2014-01-31-dd4237f Copyright (c) 2000-2014 the FFmpeg developers
  built on Jan 31 2014 06:24:45 with gcc 4.7 (Debian 4.7.2-5)
  configuration: --prefix=/home/user/ffmpeg_build --extra-cflags=-I/home/user/ffmpeg_build/include --extra-ldflags=-L/home/user/ffmpeg_build/lib --bindir=/home/user/bin --extra-libs=-ldl --enable-gpl --enable-libass --enable-libfdk-aac --enable-libopus --enable-libtheora --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvpx --enable-libx264 --enable-nonfree --enable-x11grab
  libavutil      52. 63.100 / 52. 63.100
  libavcodec     55. 49.101 / 55. 49.101
  libavformat    55. 28.101 / 55. 28.101
  libavdevice    55.  7.100 / 55.  7.100
  libavfilter     4.  1.101 /  4.  1.101
  libswscale      2.  5.101 /  2.  5.101
  libswresample   0. 17.104 /  0. 17.104
  libpostproc    52.  3.100 / 52.  3.100
[h264 @ 0x2c00460] AVC: nal size 21102612
[h264 @ 0x2c00460] missing picture in access unit with size 61
Input #0, flv, from 'a91274db-595c-43cc-86f5-30824d4c9527':
  Metadata:
    creationdate    : Mon Feb 3 08:11:35
  Duration: 00:05:44.74, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 184 kb/s
    Stream #0:0: Video: h264 (Baseline), yuv420p(tv), 264x198 [SAR 1:1 DAR 4:3], 14.08 fps, 7.50 tbr, 1k tbn, 28 tbc
    Stream #0:1: Audio: speex, 16000 Hz, mono
[libx264 @ 0x2c1fc40] using SAR=4/5
[libx264 @ 0x2c1fc40] using cpu capabilities: MMX2 SSE2Fast SSSE3 SSE4.2 AVX
[libx264 @ 0x2c1fc40] profile High, level 1.2
[libx264 @ 0x2c1fc40] 264 - core 142 r2 956c8d8 - H.264/MPEG-4 AVC codec - Copyleft 2003-2014 - http://www.videolan.org/x264.html - options: cabac=1 ref=3 deblock=1:0:0 analyse=0x3:0x113 me=hex subme=7 psy=1 psy_rd=1.00:0.00 mixed_ref=1 me_range=16 chroma_me=1 trellis=1 8x8dct=1 cqm=0 deadzone=21,11 fast_pskip=1 chroma_qp_offset=-2 threads=12 lookahead_threads=1 sliced_threads=0 nr=0 decimate=1 interlaced=0 bluray_compat=0 constrained_intra=0 bframes=3 b_pyramid=2 b_adapt=1 b_bias=0 direct=1 weightb=1 open_gop=0 weightp=2 keyint=250 keyint_min=7 scenecut=40 intra_refresh=0 rc_lookahead=40 rc=crf mbtree=1 crf=23.0 qcomp=0.60 qpmin=0 qpmax=69 qpstep=4 ip_ratio=1.40 aq=1:1.00
Output #0, flv, to 'out.flv':
  Metadata:
    creationdate    : Mon Feb 3 08:11:35
    encoder         : Lavf55.28.101
    Stream #0:0: Video: h264 (libx264) ([7][0][0][0] / 0x0007), yuv420p, 400x240 [SAR 4:5 DAR 4:3], q=-1--1, 1k tbn, 7.50 tbc
    Stream #0:1: Audio: speex ([11][0][0][0] / 0x000B), 16000 Hz, mono
Stream mapping:
  Stream #0:0 -> #0:0 (h264 -> libx264)
  Stream #0:1 -> #0:1 (copy)
Press [q] to stop, [?] for help
[h264 @ 0x2c00460] AVC: nal size 21102612
[h264 @ 0x2c00460] missing picture in access unit with size 61
[flv @ 0x2c07800] Warning: Speex stream has more than 8 frames per packet. Adobe Flash Player cannot handle this!
[h264 @ 0x2c00460] AVC: nal size 21102612
[h264 @ 0x2c00460] missing picture in access unit with size 61
[h264 @ 0x2c00460] AVC: nal size 21102613
[h264 @ 0x2c00460] missing picture in access unit with size 60
[h264 @ 0x3966f40] Reinit context to 416x320, pix_fmt: yuv420p
Input stream #0:0 frame changed from size:264x198 fmt:yuv420p to size:416x312 fmt:yuv420p
[h264 @ 0x2c00460] AVC: nal size 21102613
[h264 @ 0x2c00460] missing picture in access unit with size 60
[h264 @ 0x2c00460] AVC: nal size 21102613
[h264 @ 0x2c00460] missing picture in access unit with size 60
[h264 @ 0x2c00460] AVC: nal size 21102613
[h264 @ 0x2c00460] missing picture in access unit with size 60
[h264 @ 0x2c00460] AVC: nal size 21102613
[h264 @ 0x2c00460] missing picture in access unit with size 60
[h264 @ 0x2c00460] AVC: nal size 21102613
[h264 @ 0x2c00460] missing picture in access unit with size 60
[h264 @ 0x2c00460] AVC: nal size 21102613
[h264 @ 0x2c00460] missing picture in access unit with size 60
[h264 @ 0x2c00460] AVC: nal size 21102613B time=00:00:31.80 bitrate=  98.3kbits/s dup=0 drop=7    
[h264 @ 0x2c00460] missing picture in access unit with size 60
[h264 @ 0x2c00460] AVC: nal size 21102613
[h264 @ 0x2c00460] missing picture in access unit with size 60
[h264 @ 0x2c00460] AVC: nal size 21102613
[h264 @ 0x2c00460] missing picture in access unit with size 60
[h264 @ 0x2c00460] AVC: nal size 21102613
[h264 @ 0x2c00460] missing picture in access unit with size 60
[h264 @ 0x2c00460] AVC: nal size 21102613
[h264 @ 0x2c00460] missing picture in access unit with size 60
[h264 @ 0x2c00460] AVC: nal size 21102613
[h264 @ 0x2c00460] missing picture in access unit with size 60
[h264 @ 0x2c00460] AVC: nal size 21102613
[h264 @ 0x2c00460] missing picture in access unit with size 60
[h264 @ 0x2c00460] AVC: nal size 21102613
[h264 @ 0x2c00460] missing picture in access unit with size 60
[h264 @ 0x2c00460] AVC: nal size 21102613
[h264 @ 0x2c00460] missing picture in access unit with size 60
[h264 @ 0x2c00460] AVC: nal size 21102613
[h264 @ 0x2c00460] missing picture in access unit with size 60
[h264 @ 0x2c00460] AVC: nal size 21102613
[h264 @ 0x2c00460] missing picture in access unit with size 60
[h264 @ 0x2c00460] AVC: nal size 21102613B time=00:01:07.63 bitrate=  93.2kbits/s dup=0 drop=7    
[h264 @ 0x2c00460] missing picture in access unit with size 60
[h264 @ 0x2c00460] AVC: nal size 21102613
[h264 @ 0x2c00460] missing picture in access unit with size 60
[h264 @ 0x2c00460] AVC: nal size 21102613
[h264 @ 0x2c00460] missing picture in access unit with size 60
[h264 @ 0x2c00460] AVC: nal size 21102613
[h264 @ 0x2c00460] missing picture in access unit with size 60
[h264 @ 0x2c00460] AVC: nal size 21102613
[h264 @ 0x2c00460] missing picture in access unit with size 60
[h264 @ 0x2c00460] AVC: nal size 21102613
[h264 @ 0x2c00460] missing picture in access unit with size 60
[h264 @ 0x2c00460] AVC: nal size 21102613
[h264 @ 0x2c00460] missing picture in access unit with size 60
[h264 @ 0x2c00460] AVC: nal size 21102613
[h264 @ 0x2c00460] missing picture in access unit with size 60
[h264 @ 0x2c00460] AVC: nal size 21102613
[h264 @ 0x2c00460] missing picture in access unit with size 60
[h264 @ 0x2c00460] AVC: nal size 21102613
[h264 @ 0x2c00460] missing picture in access unit with size 60
[h264 @ 0x2c00460] AVC: nal size 21102613B time=00:01:42.55 bitrate=  92.1kbits/s dup=0 drop=7    
[h264 @ 0x2c00460] missing picture in access unit with size 60
[h264 @ 0x2c00460] AVC: nal size 21102613
[h264 @ 0x2c00460] missing picture in access unit with size 60
[h264 @ 0x2c00460] AVC: nal size 21102613
[h264 @ 0x2c00460] missing picture in access unit with size 60
[h264 @ 0x2c00460] AVC: nal size 21102613
[h264 @ 0x2c00460] missing picture in access unit with size 60
[h264 @ 0x2c00460] AVC: nal size 21102613
[h264 @ 0x2c00460] missing picture in access unit with size 60
[h264 @ 0x2c00460] AVC: nal size 21102613
[h264 @ 0x2c00460] missing picture in access unit with size 60
[h264 @ 0x2c00460] AVC: nal size 21102613
[h264 @ 0x2c00460] missing picture in access unit with size 60
[h264 @ 0x2c00460] AVC: nal size 21102613
[h264 @ 0x2c00460] missing picture in access unit with size 60
[h264 @ 0x2c00460] AVC: nal size 21102613
[h264 @ 0x2c00460] missing picture in access unit with size 60
[h264 @ 0x2c00460] AVC: nal size 21102613
[h264 @ 0x2c00460] missing picture in access unit with size 60
[h264 @ 0x2c00460] AVC: nal size 21102613
[h264 @ 0x2c00460] missing picture in access unit with size 60
[h264 @ 0x2c00460] AVC: nal size 21102613B time=00:02:17.71 bitrate=  92.4kbits/s dup=0 drop=7    
[h264 @ 0x2c00460] missing picture in access unit with size 60
[h264 @ 0x2c00460] AVC: nal size 21102613
[h264 @ 0x2c00460] missing picture in access unit with size 60
[h264 @ 0x2c00460] AVC: nal size 21102613
[h264 @ 0x2c00460] missing picture in access unit with size 60
[h264 @ 0x2c00460] AVC: nal size 21102613
[h264 @ 0x2c00460] missing picture in access unit with size 60
[h264 @ 0x2c00460] AVC: nal size 21102613
[h264 @ 0x2c00460] missing picture in access unit with size 60
[h264 @ 0x2c00460] AVC: nal size 21102613
[h264 @ 0x2c00460] missing picture in access unit with size 60
[h264 @ 0x2c00460] AVC: nal size 21102613
[h264 @ 0x2c00460] missing picture in access unit with size 60
[h264 @ 0x2c00460] AVC: nal size 21102613
[h264 @ 0x2c00460] missing picture in access unit with size 60
[h264 @ 0x2c00460] AVC: nal size 21102613
[h264 @ 0x2c00460] missing picture in access unit with size 60
[h264 @ 0x2c00460] AVC: nal size 21102613
[h264 @ 0x2c00460] missing picture in access unit with size 60
[h264 @ 0x2c00460] AVC: nal size 21102613B time=00:02:50.23 bitrate=  95.1kbits/s dup=0 drop=7    
[h264 @ 0x2c00460] missing picture in access unit with size 60
[h264 @ 0x2c00460] AVC: nal size 21102613
[h264 @ 0x2c00460] missing picture in access unit with size 60
[h264 @ 0x2c00460] AVC: nal size 21102613
[h264 @ 0x2c00460] missing picture in access unit with size 60
[h264 @ 0x2c00460] AVC: nal size 21102613
[h264 @ 0x2c00460] missing picture in access unit with size 60
[h264 @ 0x2c00460] AVC: nal size 21102613
[h264 @ 0x2c00460] missing picture in access unit with size 60
[h264 @ 0x2c00460] AVC: nal size 21102613
[h264 @ 0x2c00460] missing picture in access unit with size 60
[h264 @ 0x2c00460] AVC: nal size 21102613
[h264 @ 0x2c00460] missing picture in access unit with size 60
[h264 @ 0x2c00460] AVC: nal size 21102613
[h264 @ 0x2c00460] missing picture in access unit with size 60
[h264 @ 0x2c00460] AVC: nal size 21102613
[h264 @ 0x2c00460] missing picture in access unit with size 60
[h264 @ 0x2c00460] AVC: nal size 21102613
[h264 @ 0x2c00460] missing picture in access unit with size 60
[h264 @ 0x2c00460] AVC: nal size 21102613B time=00:03:25.83 bitrate=  94.0kbits/s dup=0 drop=7    
[h264 @ 0x2c00460] missing picture in access unit with size 60
[h264 @ 0x2c00460] AVC: nal size 21102613
[h264 @ 0x2c00460] missing picture in access unit with size 60
[h264 @ 0x2c00460] AVC: nal size 21102613
[h264 @ 0x2c00460] missing picture in access unit with size 60
[h264 @ 0x2c00460] AVC: nal size 21102613
[h264 @ 0x2c00460] missing picture in access unit with size 60
[h264 @ 0x2c00460] AVC: nal size 21102613
[h264 @ 0x2c00460] missing picture in access unit with size 60
[h264 @ 0x2c00460] AVC: nal size 21102613
[h264 @ 0x2c00460] missing picture in access unit with size 60
[h264 @ 0x2c00460] AVC: nal size 21102613
[h264 @ 0x2c00460] missing picture in access unit with size 60
[h264 @ 0x2c00460] AVC: nal size 21102613
[h264 @ 0x2c00460] missing picture in access unit with size 60
[h264 @ 0x2c00460] AVC: nal size 21102613
[h264 @ 0x2c00460] missing picture in access unit with size 60
[h264 @ 0x2c00460] AVC: nal size 21102613
[h264 @ 0x2c00460] missing picture in access unit with size 60
[h264 @ 0x2c00460] AVC: nal size 21102613
[h264 @ 0x2c00460] missing picture in access unit with size 60
[h264 @ 0x2c00460] AVC: nal size 21102613B time=00:03:59.67 bitrate=  95.3kbits/s dup=0 drop=7    
[h264 @ 0x2c00460] missing picture in access unit with size 60
[h264 @ 0x2c00460] AVC: nal size 21102613
[h264 @ 0x2c00460] missing picture in access unit with size 60
[h264 @ 0x2c00460] AVC: nal size 21102613
[h264 @ 0x2c00460] missing picture in access unit with size 60
[h264 @ 0x2c00460] AVC: nal size 21102613
[h264 @ 0x2c00460] missing picture in access unit with size 60
[h264 @ 0x2c00460] AVC: nal size 21102613
[h264 @ 0x2c00460] missing picture in access unit with size 60
[h264 @ 0x2c00460] AVC: nal size 21102613
[h264 @ 0x2c00460] missing picture in access unit with size 60
[h264 @ 0x2c00460] AVC: nal size 21102613
[h264 @ 0x2c00460] missing picture in access unit with size 60
[h264 @ 0x2c00460] AVC: nal size 21102613
[h264 @ 0x2c00460] missing picture in access unit with size 60
[h264 @ 0x2c00460] AVC: nal size 21102613
[h264 @ 0x2c00460] missing picture in access unit with size 60
[h264 @ 0x2c00460] AVC: nal size 21102613
[h264 @ 0x2c00460] missing picture in access unit with size 60
[h264 @ 0x2c00460] AVC: nal size 21102613
[h264 @ 0x2c00460] missing picture in access unit with size 60
[h264 @ 0x2c00460] AVC: nal size 21102613B time=00:04:36.85 bitrate=  93.9kbits/s dup=0 drop=7    
[h264 @ 0x2c00460] missing picture in access unit with size 60
[h264 @ 0x2c00460] AVC: nal size 21102613
[h264 @ 0x2c00460] missing picture in access unit with size 60
[h264 @ 0x2c00460] AVC: nal size 21102613
[h264 @ 0x2c00460] missing picture in access unit with size 60
[h264 @ 0x2c00460] AVC: nal size 21102613
[h264 @ 0x2c00460] missing picture in access unit with size 60
[h264 @ 0x2c00460] AVC: nal size 21102613
[h264 @ 0x2c00460] missing picture in access unit with size 60
[h264 @ 0x2c00460] AVC: nal size 21102613
[h264 @ 0x2c00460] missing picture in access unit with size 60
[h264 @ 0x2c00460] AVC: nal size 21102613
[h264 @ 0x2c00460] missing picture in access unit with size 60
[h264 @ 0x2c00460] AVC: nal size 21102613
[h264 @ 0x2c00460] missing picture in access unit with size 60
[h264 @ 0x2c00460] AVC: nal size 21102613
[h264 @ 0x2c00460] missing picture in access unit with size 60
[h264 @ 0x2c00460] AVC: nal size 21102613
[h264 @ 0x2c00460] missing picture in access unit with size 60
[h264 @ 0x2c00460] AVC: nal size 21102613B time=00:05:11.11 bitrate=  94.2kbits/s dup=0 drop=7    
[h264 @ 0x2c00460] missing picture in access unit with size 60
[h264 @ 0x2c00460] AVC: nal size 21102613
[h264 @ 0x2c00460] missing picture in access unit with size 60
[h264 @ 0x2c00460] AVC: nal size 21102613
[h264 @ 0x2c00460] missing picture in access unit with size 60
[h264 @ 0x2c00460] AVC: nal size 21102613
[h264 @ 0x2c00460] missing picture in access unit with size 60
[h264 @ 0x2c00460] AVC: nal size 21102613
[h264 @ 0x2c00460] missing picture in access unit with size 60
[h264 @ 0x2c00460] AVC: nal size 21102613
[h264 @ 0x2c00460] missing picture in access unit with size 60
[h264 @ 0x2c00460] AVC: nal size 21102613
[h264 @ 0x2c00460] missing picture in access unit with size 60
[h264 @ 0x2c00460] AVC: nal size 21102613
[h264 @ 0x2c00460] missing picture in access unit with size 60
[h264 @ 0x2c00460] AVC: nal size 21102613
[h264 @ 0x2c00460] missing picture in access unit with size 60
[h264 @ 0x2c00460] AVC: nal size 21102613
[h264 @ 0x2c00460] missing picture in access unit with size 60
frame= 2582 fps=505 q=-1.0 Lsize=    4120kB time=00:05:44.73 bitrate=  97.9kbits/s dup=0 drop=7    
video:3596kB audio:203kB subtitle:0 data:0 global headers:0kB muxing overhead 8.423537%
[libx264 @ 0x2c1fc40] frame I:12    Avg QP:16.00  size: 13286
[libx264 @ 0x2c1fc40] frame P:768   Avg QP:18.47  size:  3684
[libx264 @ 0x2c1fc40] frame B:1802  Avg QP:22.03  size:   385
[libx264 @ 0x2c1fc40] consecutive B-frames:  3.9%  6.7%  7.7% 81.8%
[libx264 @ 0x2c1fc40] mb I  I16..4:  7.4% 55.1% 37.5%
[libx264 @ 0x2c1fc40] mb P  I16..4:  2.1%  4.5%  1.1%  P16..4: 37.9% 25.8% 15.0%  0.0%  0.0%    skip:13.7%
[libx264 @ 0x2c1fc40] mb B  I16..4:  0.1%  0.2%  0.0%  B16..8: 32.7%  3.3%  0.5%  direct: 1.5%  skip:61.6%  L0:40.5% L1:52.3% BI: 7.2%
[libx264 @ 0x2c1fc40] 8x8 transform intra:57.9% inter:60.8%
[libx264 @ 0x2c1fc40] coded y,uvDC,uvAC intra: 55.0% 68.7% 41.5% inter: 16.3% 22.2% 2.6%
[libx264 @ 0x2c1fc40] i16 v,h,dc,p: 19% 20%  5% 56%
[libx264 @ 0x2c1fc40] i8 v,h,dc,ddl,ddr,vr,hd,vl,hu: 20% 23% 20%  5%  7%  6%  8%  6%  7%
[libx264 @ 0x2c1fc40] i4 v,h,dc,ddl,ddr,vr,hd,vl,hu: 31% 21% 12%  5%  7%  6%  7%  6%  6%
[libx264 @ 0x2c1fc40] i8c dc,h,v,p: 51% 20% 22%  6%
[libx264 @ 0x2c1fc40] Weighted P-Frames: Y:4.2% UV:2.2%
[libx264 @ 0x2c1fc40] ref P L0: 57.4% 13.0% 22.6%  6.9%  0.1%
[libx264 @ 0x2c1fc40] ref B L0: 86.4% 11.2%  2.4%
[libx264 @ 0x2c1fc40] ref B L1: 95.6%  4.4%
[libx264 @ 0x2c1fc40] kb/s:85.40
```

What does "missing picture in access unit with size " mean ?

Thanks in advance .

Comment: Please include the complete `ffmpeg` console output, then select it and press ctrl+k instead of using backticks (`).

Comment: Can you please [download a newer version](http://ffmpeg.org/download.html)? Yours is quite outdated and chances are that's a bug that's already fixed. However, the video should be encoded regardless. What's the output, or what is the actual problem?

Comment: @slhck , i did update my ffmpeg version to this git-2014-01-31-dd4237f . Do look at my edited notes .

Comment: Unfortunately I don't see any edited notes.

Comment: @slhck , please do check now .